# How can the government improve employment in a capitalistic society?

Tags: employment, capitalism

When unemployment rates are rising, the blame is often put on the government, and it is said that "if the government were more competent, we'd be employed". I'm trying to understand this statement, and impart of that, I ask this question: Exactly how can government boost up employment numbers in a capitalistic society?

Comment: This seems too broad as almost every policy government can come up with can at least indirectly affect employment rates. It will also be opinion based as you can find arguments for directly opposing policies saying they will improve employment rates.

Comment: If you think about it, if they economy is hands free from the government, how can the government through policy demand that more people are hired? The only way I see is they get hired in govt itself. Excuse me, if I misunderstood something about capitalism here. @JOntia

Comment: The government could kill the poor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owI7DOeO_yg.

Comment: It's a very broad question. In the US the go-to tools are interest rates (via the gov't-appointed FED-Board-of-Governors), tax policy, and trade policy.

Comment: Are the policies you told capitalistic in nature? @Pete W

Comment: That's a question for the "worldly philosophers" . . .

Comment: This question is begging for a *no true Scotsman* type of answer (or in this case, a *no true capitalist* type of answer).

Comment: I mean , I clearly stated my understanding of capitalism. The no true scotsman lies in the issue of how exactly something is defined. If my understanding of capitalism is wrong, I'll be ready to listen how it is so.

Comment: The title question and the body question seem at odds with each other. "Improve employment" could relate to the quality and nature of the relationship and compensation. While the body seems to be talking merely about the number of employed people and unemployed people.

Answer (score 21):

There are many methods, just as there are many reasons companies will increase or decrease their staff. They range from direct spending, to subsidies to businesses, to providing a better environment for businesses to operate.

The government can employ people directly. In most countries the government is a major employer in areas like schools, the armed forces, police, social services, and possibly state-owned industries. Also often healthcare and further/higher education are state-owned or state controlled (although those are more likely to be done via private companies or other entities).

A traditional method going back to the Depression in the 1930s is to offer funding for infrastructure projects. Roosevelt's [New Deal](https://www.history.com/news/new-deal-infrastructure-projects-fdr) included schemes such as the Hoover Dam and many projects around roads, bridges, and tunnels, which employed a large number of people.

Countries can also vary tax rates and other things to make it easier or cheaper to employ people. Lowering payroll taxes, for instance, will make it cheaper to take on staff by reducing outgoings. In the slump after the 2008 crash, the [OECD recommended](https://www.oecd.org/newsroom/taxreformcancreatejobs.htm) this kind of reform. This can be extended to programs that cover some part of workers salaries, as with the [furlough scheme in the UK](https://www.peoplemanagement.co.uk/news/articles/uk-should-be-ready-bring-back-form-furlough#gref) to prevent COVID-related unemployment which provided a large part of workers' salaries; or smaller-scale schemes with tax breaks (effectively money off the tax bill) for employing the long-term unemployed.

There are a wide range of things that can encourage businesses to expand. This might include money/tax breaks for research and development, but could also include non-financial things such as reducing/eliminating tariffs and making international trade easier. Stabilising the economy makes it easier to plan and invest. Lowering interest rates (under the control of central banks) makes it easier to borrow to invest and hence to expand and take on jobs.

Answer (score 8):

One way is by providing loans. A government may provide loans to unemployed people. Sometimes these loans are subsidised. Say the bank provides loan at 10%, the government provides the loan at 8 or 7 to motivated individuals by analysing their project blueprints. You may call them start ups or entrepreneurs or self help groups. These people start something to sustain their livelihood and also employ some people if necessary. Had the government needed to provide jobs in the public sector itself to all those people the cost would have been more. Besides, money creates money.

Then there is contractual employment. Instead of providing jobs which is permanent in nature to **x** number of people in the public sector at **2y Money/month** the government may employ **2x** number of people in the public sector at **y Money/month** in public sector in a job which is temporary in nature. Say 12 months. The appointment letter often includes a clause which reads "the undersigned may terminate/extend the contract whenever it deems necessary". Luckily/unluckily these people work forever at very low income.

Comment: These are mechanisms that can work, at least temporarily, but wouldn't this level of intervention make the society not really capitalist?

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, before the Great Depression, economic thought generally did not consider government intervention in the economy. Since the Great Depression however, Keynesian economic thought has been dominant. In short, Keynesianism views the fundamental cause of a recession as a sudden deficit in demand. This deficit means that businesses can no longer sustain their employees, since they are facing reduced sales. In turn, those fired employees don’t buy as much without a paycheck and demand continues to drop, causing more workers to be let go, and this cycle causes the recession to worsen. This is summed up in the maxim that one person’s spending is another person’s income.

Keynesianism therefore believes that government policy can make up this demand deficit. The thinking goes, government programs can stop businesses from letting go of more employees and prevent newly unemployed people from cutting spending. Now, the vicious cycle of the last paragraph is disrupted, since government money has made up for the demand lost as people cut back on spending.

Practically, Keynesian policies are either fiscal or monetary. Fiscal policy consists of unemployment benefits, cutting taxes (so people have more income), infrastructure projects, bailouts, or stimulus checks, among others. Monetary policies involve bond purchases and sales by the Federal Reserve; skipping over the complexity, these transactions (open market operations) affect the prevailing interest rate. When interest rates are lower, businesses invest more (because it is cheaper to borrow money to make investments in their business), purchasing capital equipment and stimulating demand.

So in the face of a recession, the government has tools to confront it and ameliorate it. Of course, the real-world implementation of Keynesian theory is much more complex and messy and government intervention is not always successful. The main point is, the government can strongly influence the state of the economy and the unemployment rate.

Is this capitalism? Yes, emphatically yes. Keynesian thought is slightly left of neoliberalism but at the furthest left could only be associated with social democratic thought. Social democracy, fundamentally, is a form of capitalism. Socialism is defined by taking control of capital, or private property, from the personal ownership of the capitalist class and vesting ownership in either the state or the workers (private property is economically productive equipment like machines, in contrast to personal property like your toothbrush). So social democracy is capitalism, since it does not completely replace private property ownership.

Comment: I'd say that a major part of why investments climb on lower interest rates is that the return on capital is poor on having cash, unleveraged equity or liquid assets. When interest rates are high, the return on "investment" of repaying loans, deleveraging etc is good, so capital tends to get used for that (as opposed to investing in technology, new products, more capacity). It is not necessarily the cost of borrowing, but the opportunity cost of the capital spenditure.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is simply to reduce the number of hours people work each week. Keynes supposed that in late capitalistic society people will be working for around fifteen hours a week, or a two day working week.

In Iceland, between 2014-19, a 4 day working week was trialed across a number of different companies and government departments with a majority reporting  productivity remaining at the same levels or increasing. The trials eventially included 2,500 employees or 1% of Icelands total workforce.

This has led to Icelands unions negotiating a right to a 4 day working week for everyone. Other benefits included less burn-out, increased mental and physical health, more time for family and friends and hence increased social cohesion.

Marx said that Capitalism entails alienation. All the evidence points towards Marx's conclusion except of course, we simply do not use this term in capitalistic society, instead we talk about a pandemic of loneliness.

In 2018, a report by the Kaiser Family Foundation reported that 60 million americans said that they often or always felt lonely or socially isolated. This is before the pandemic and is an outcome of what Marx called alienation. Not only are we alienated from our work but from our fellow human beings, because most of our waking hours are spent at work or recovering from work.

Keynes recommendation of a two day working week would not only reduce alienation but also increase employment. Of course, capital is not going to easily countenance such a radical reduction in working hours but it is long overdue and if we can put a man on the moon or put build a laptop with a million times the complexity of the computers in the Apollo mission, we can certainly go over to such a radical overhaul of the working week.

For this to work, this would have to be legislated for. Because if we wait for business to do this, we'll be waiting till hell freezes over. And legislation means that the government has to intervene.

Comment: Historically work week length legislation has always followed after work week length reductions in industry for the majority of people. Basically as technology advances it takes less work to produce enough to support a person, so everyone needs to work less. Legislation follows on the heels of this to make politicians look good. But if you actually do force hours down in an economy that wasn't already headed there then you're just cutting production of necessary resources and people have to find other jobs to take up the slack. And business has very little say unless they maintain a cartel.

Answer (score 4):

So, you're going to run into some definitional issues here...  Along with the fact that the fields of economics and politics have separate viewpoints on questions like this.

To start with, from an economics point of view, the more the government is fiddling around trying to force particular outcomes the less you can call the economy "capitalist".  In many ways, if you're asking the question you've already discarded one of the premises.

The second issue is that "improve" is kind of nebulous with regard to employment...  Do you just mean that everyone has a "job"?  That everyone is "busy"?  That there are no "idle resources" that need to be "stimulated" back into production?

The government's fairly good at doing those surface-level things.  You can certainly take taxed or printed money and go find *something* to have the unemployed do.  Or make cheap loans available.  Or a few dozen other things, the other answers here cover them all pretty well.

But if you mean "improve" as in "make sure everyone's doing the most productive thing they could be doing"...  It's just not feasible for the government to figure that out.  The sheer volume of data required to sort it out for everyone on a national scale exceeds even our modern communications technology.

And so that's why you get "make work" projects that consume valuable resources from the economy to produce less valuable products.  This reduces the overall standard of living in order to achieve the illusion that everyone is busy, happy, and productive.  But that illusion is what gets politicians re-elected, so they have no incentive not to take that route at every opportunity.  It's quick, it's easy, and it buys the loyalty of their constituents without having to spend a single penny of their own money.

From an economics point of view, it drives up the price of labor and competes for resources with other potentially profitable ventures, thereby decreasing the energy the economy puts into long-term sustainable growth.

So that's the question you have to answer:  What is your ultimate goal.

If it's long-term stability and prosperity, then the best thing to do is to create a stable, reliable environment where people can accurately estimate the potential costs and benefits of their plans.  Respect for private property, enforcement of contracts, predictable long-term tax rates, that kind of thing.

If it's just to get re-elected, then crank up the printing presses and just go hire all the unemployed people to do...  something... anything...  Precisely what doesn't really matter, but make it at least sound like it's something helpful.  Most people won't actually bother to check if all the bridges you're building actually lead anyplace or not.

Really this question has more to do with economics than with politics.  Politics would cover how you convince people to go along with whatever economic strategy you pick, but picking one that "works" is purely economics.

To that end I would recommend "Economics in One Lesson", by Henry Hazlitt and/or "That Which is Seen and That Which is Not Seen", by Fredric Bastiat.  They both break down the economic consequences of some of the most common "improvement" strategies.  Then it's just a matter of picking the ones that give the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In a pure capitalist society there is no minimum wage, and absolutely no safety net.

So the theory is that the unemployment rate will naturally be reduced, through the following mechanism: If you are unemployed, since there is no safety net, at some point you run out of reserves, and you need to get food and other essentials to continue to live. There is no (legal) mechanism to obtain these, other than to work. Since there is no minimum wage, you should be able to find someone to employ you, even if the payment is as low as one slice of bread per day. In theory, if the price of labour approaches zero, there must be *someone* willing to employ you. And even if you don't find someone to give you that slice of bread, you won't be alive for much longer, so you won't count as unemployed any more.

Thus unemployment is reduced.

On the contrary, in a society with safety nets and minimum wages (which wouldn't be a pure capitalist society), some workers may be priced out of the market, if their skills are worth less than the minimum wage. Also the safety net means that their life will not end if they don't get a job, thus the unemployment statistic will remain positive.

Comment: This theory breaks down when the market wage is insufficient to provide a non-starvation diet (and also shelter, clothing, ...). The working poor work and starve in that case, and therevy go away. Not a nice place to live.

Comment: @o.m.: True, but then the're not unemployed any more :p

Comment: Those people would become beggars instead of working for a too low income, if begging provides a higher income than work.

Comment: @PauloEbermann Those people are beggars in any system; either they panhandle on the street or in the welfare office.  Safety nets don't reduce begging, they just change who the beggars beg from.

Comment: People do not sit idly by and starve to preserve the purity of the system, at least not indefinitely. This economic insecurity is the cause of a lot of political instability around the world.

Comment: @pjc50 Actually the Guilded Age gave birth to the communist movements all over the world. Communism is a children of unfettered capitalism.

Comment: It's a mistake to think that there are no safety nets in a Capitalist system.  There very definitely are.  They're just not run by the government with no regard to cost.  But churches, social clubs, fraternal organizations, and mutual insurance groups were all quite common prior to the construction of the modern welfare state. And, statistically, did a better job of picking people up and putting them back on their feet than the modern system does.

Comment: @o.m.  Whether or not the market wage rate pays enough to live on has more to do with the level of economic development than the actual economic system. If wages don't pay enough to live on, it's because food, clothing, and shelter are scarce relative to the number of people who need them.  When you go back to the time periods you're talking about, that level of poverty was the norm around the world. The trick is to pick an economic system which encourages development of more resources so the scarcity disappears.

Comment: @Perkins, my point is that one cannot get workers for less than a living wage for very long, unless those workers have other sources of funding. In a "pure capitalist" society, as posed by the OP, they don't.

Comment: @o.m.  In aggregate, yes.  Always.  But, if you examine any particular society, even under pure capitalism, you will find quite a few workers who have those other sources of funding.  Juveniles supported by their parents, retired people who just want a little extra spending money to supplement their savings, etc.  And its these people that requiring every job provide a "living wage" hurts, because there are plenty of jobs that don't produce that much, but that would be perfectly adequate for these classes of worker. Instead they have to compete with more serious workers, and often lose.

Answer (score 3):

In the United States, the Federal Reserve has [two mandates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Reserve):

1. Maximizing Employment
2. Stabilizing Prices

Two of the big levers they have for controlling unemployment are

1. Interest Rates
2. Money Supply

Generally, the Fed will try to lower unemployment by heating up the economy. They heat up the economy by lowering interest rates and increasing money supply. And the converse if they want to put on the brakes.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll reframe the question somewhat to *...boost up employment numbers **in the long term** ...*.  Otherwise a Keynesian stimulus might very well work in the short term.

Second, a capitalist society *within a democracy* reflects the choices made by the electorate.

- In a pure dog-eat-dog libertarian system you might see no welfare, no minimum wage, no regulations, no job security, almost no government spending etc...
- In an extremely regulated system, you might - while the means of production nominally remain in private hands - see the opposite:  very high minimum wages, heavy regulations, cradle-to-grave employment, as much government spending as tax collection allows.

In practice, democracies will typically navigate, not always very gracefully, between the two.

**The reason I am laying this out is to make clear that the libertarian ideal isn't necessarily an ideal state, either economically or from a societal viewpoint.  What is "ideal" for taxpayers or bosses may not be acceptable for voters or workers.
These are some possible things to look at, but a theoretically "perfect" system will not be that great if it gets rejected by voters**

Third, *employment and unemployment* can be elusive terms.  Does it count if someone stops looking for work?  What about unreported work?    Does a person sitting in front of an escalator telling people which way is up count?

So, what can a free-market oriented government do?

##### Reform welfare and job protection laws.

A welfare net that is too generous and too easy to access will reduce employment.  At the same time, welfare was brought in during the Great Depression for *economic reasons*, to let people keep on consuming rather than trigger a deflationary cycle.  And, when it comes to welfare, besides the economic reasons, there are also ethical reasons - helping those who truly can't support themselves.

But an overly generous welfare state can certainly come at a cost, for example in the [Netherlands](https://archives.history.ac.uk/history-in-focus/welfare/articles/nottinghamc.html):

> Then came the crisis in the western economies. In the 1970s the Netherlands saw a massive decline in agricultural employment, a halving of family owned retail business and the virtual disappearance of traditional industries such as shoemaking, textiles and shipbuilding. As a result the newly relaxed welfare state ended up supporting a fundamental reconstruction of the labour market. In 1970 for every 100 in employment there were 46 on state benefit; by 1990 the figure rose to 85. By the 1982 election all parties accepted the need to cut state benefits.

One example that is sometimes claimed to be a (mixed?) success is [PRWORA, passed in 1996 under Bill Clinton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Responsibility_and_Work_Opportunity_Act#Consequences)

> Welfare and poverty rates both declined during the late 1990s, leading many commentators to declare that **the legislation was a success.** One editorial in The New Republic opined, "A broad consensus now holds that welfare reform was certainly not a disaster—and that it may, in fact, have worked much as its designers had hoped." **However, the number of welfare recipients declined much more sharply than the poverty rate,** with a national average of 56% reduction in welfare caseloads and 1% reduction in poverty. The number of children living in extreme poverty, defined as a household income below 50% of the poverty line, increased, with a sharper increase among African-American families.

Job protection in Western economies run the gamut from [at-will employment laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment), as seen in some US states, and very restrictive systems, like France, where large scale economic layoffs (>50) need to be submitted to the government ["for review"](https://lentreprise.lexpress.fr/rh-management/droit-travail/plan-social-ou-pse-ce-qu-il-faut-savoir_1808923.html).

Pushed too far, job protection laws can motivate employers to either not hire or else pursue automation extensively.  On the other hand, *again the "ideal" free-market ideology runs against the self-interest of the electorate.  And... are those at-will US states really paragons of economic vigor?

The risk side of things can be seen in [India](https://www.economist.com/asia/2017/09/14/ever-more-indians-are-struggling-to-find-work):

> The rules are indeed onerous. In many states, firms with more than 100 employees must seek government approval to fire a single worker. As a result, many resort to contractors to fill their payrolls with temporary hires, a solution that evades red tape but produces neither dedicated staff nor a happy workplace. Other companies simply choose to stay small: some 98.6% of non-farm businesses have fewer than 10 workers. This carries a long-term cost in productivity. Indian garment-makers, for example, tend to be tiny.

##### Have better educated workers

Modern economies thrive on skilled workforces.  While there are certainly jobs where paying the least possible to the worst-paid is a competitive advantage (flipping burgers, for example), those do not necessarily lead to strong economies.

Employers will employ more and be more competitive if they can find workers who are skilled and with appropriate education.  "Appropriate" does not mean that everyone having a PhD is desirable but good-enough literacy and numeracy are always valued, and not always delivered in Western democracies.

##### Avoid long-term unemployed

The long term unemployed have traditionally found it very hard to reenter the job market, leading to part of the population being excluded.  Spending money on retraining before skills atrophy is something that the Nordic countries [typically are seen as getting right](https://www.intereconomics.eu/contents/year/2016/number/3/article/lessons-learnt-from-the-nordics-how-to-fight-long-term-unemployment.html).

> This study examines policies that can successfully address long-term unemployment. It focuses on Denmark and Sweden, where, despite sizeable job losses during the crisis, labour market indicators are at present better than in any other EU country. By looking at the interaction between labour market flexibility (especially in hiring and firing regulations) and passive and active policies, we argue that well-designed active policies matter more than labour market flexibility for employment.

##### Spend wisely.

In theory a government could employ workers directly and "solve" the employment problem.  In practice, doing so requires taxes, which will have to be paid by taxpayers.  Unless of course the government jobs produce wealth themselves.  But in that case, would they not have better performed by free market actors?  The experience of the UK in the 70s shows the limits of nationalized companies.

However, foregoing all, or most, government spending as per some libertarian utopias may also not be that productive.  I've already covered education, but let's take health care.  Nationalized health care systems absorb 12% of GDP in Europe and Canada.  Vs 18% in the US (9% government spending, 9% private).

Employers "on the hook" to provide health benefits in the US might rightfully rue a system where the, [smaller](https://www.healthsystemtracker.org/chart-collection/health-spending-u-s-compare-countries-2/), costs are taken care of by the government.  And labor mobility - choosing to leave one job for another - can be reduced when the risks of losing one's health coverage has to be taken into account.

##### Don't try to pick winners

Countries too often try to pursue "sexy" industrial programs.  Ever heard of the [Japanese 5th generation computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_generation_computer)?  No?  The lost European commission plan for [*analog* HDTV](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg13818791-500-europe-to-subsidise-widescreen-tv/)?  Or how about the aim to promote small companies rather than larger ones.  France and Canada both have special rules for small companies (50 and 20 employees respectively) but this can backfire when it causes firms to consciously avoid getting bigger.

##### Have predictable and fair regulations and legal systems

People should be able to launch companies without the state swooping in and expropriating them.  Suppliers and workers should be able to sue for moneys owed.  Honest failures should be tolerated as a necessary part of innovation, even as fraud like the [Theranos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theranos#Criminal_proceedings) affair should be heavily penalized.

##### "Promote innovation and diversification"

Ideally a country would pursue new economic opportunities as they appear and cut back from old industries as they sunset.  Nokia, shifting from paper mills to cellphones would be an example of the former while subsidizing coal mining in the US would be an example of failing to do the latter.

Yet Nokia's fall from grace is also a warning that countries do not come equal:  a small country "handles" differently from a big country, no matter the wishful thinking.

High tech innovation, with appropriate links from R&D to commercialization and a vibrant ecosystem of new companies is the holy grail.

But with everyone shooting for it, it might be best for a government to work on the basics rather than try to fine-tune everything which is unlikely to work.

##### Watch your payroll taxes

Many countries levy a considerable amount of tax specifically from payrolls, for various reasons (funding health care or retirement are 2 typical ones).  This can carry the disadvantages of high minimum wages (high cost to the employer) without its benefits (higher purchasing power to employees).

##### Adjust the minimum wage.

This in theory should lead to higher employment, but some studies have also claimed that too low a minimum wage discourages people from working and also lowers consumption.  I'd link to something supporting that, but it is such a contentious subject that I struggle to find a middle ground study on short notice.  On the other hand, really high minimum wages may truly limit marginal economic jobs - hiring that extra staff for positions with only marginal returns.

Let's say that too high a minimum wage can reduce employment but too low *will* be painful to individuals and might not help that much, and that a country will have to evaluate where it sits.

##### Reducing work hours

This is a possible approach, but its impact is far from clear.  Look for example at France's [seesaw in unemployment rate](https://www.statista.com/statistics/263697/unemployment-rate-in-france/) around the 1998 [Loi Aubry](https://www.lefigaro.fr/conjoncture/2018/02/09/20002-20180209ARTFIG00319-les-35heures-continuent-de-peser-sur-la-france.php) limiting to 35 hr/week.

> The first Aubry law to reduce working time was at the origin of the competitive dropout of our economy. It continues to weigh on businesses and administrations.

One problem is seen in the 4.0 or 4.5 day/workweeks.  It might be fine for a large company to "partition" its 500 "undifferentiated" factory floor workers to just hire 10% more of them.  But a small company may mostly need *one* accountant or marketer.  Not 7/8th of one + an 1/8th of another.

#### Conclusion

Most Western democracies at least pay lip service to the free market model, but the actual outcomes, both in terms of aggregate economic efficiency and in terms of individual happiness vary widely.  Many would fault the US model, but few would also fully endorse either Greece or France with its 55+% (pre-covid) of government [gdp spending](https://tradingeconomics.com/france/government-spending-to-gdp).

The Nordic countries - Sweden, Denmark, Finland (leaving out Norway due to its oil wealth component) are seen by some to be compelling models, but their approach has [evolved over time](https://tradingeconomics.com/sweden/government-spending-to-gdp) and in any case may not be that easy to scale up in bigger countries with lower levels of [trust in government](https://data.oecd.org/gga/trust-in-government.htm).

##### p.p.s. Watch automation trends carefully

The [there-are-only-so-many-jobs fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lump_of_labour_fallacy) has a long history. People did lose factory jobs to robots but in a healthy economic system job demand moved upscale (think the guy who fixes the robots or the designer).  What is somewhat new is that whole job categories such as accounting, [legal services](https://www.bustedcubicle.com/features/industry-disrupted/legal-services), or [retail sales](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/retail-loses-11000-jobs-in-september-145131614.html) are contracting to automation or new distribution models (Amazon, Netflix, online newspapers).

It's probably not worthwhile to try to hold this back overmuch - a country would lose too much international competitiveness - but learning how to adapt to it will become ever more important.  [Race against the Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_Against_the_Machine#Criticism) for example made dubious claims that we can all be digital creators.  Yet, the existence of some very rich YouTubers with 1M+ followers does not mean that the system can be scaled up to where we **all** have 1M+ followers to our creations.  The existence of well-paid, hard to outsource or automate, jobs like massage therapists or personal chefs does not mean that everyone will have thriving businesses being personal chefs (to whom?).

Governments will increasingly have find the best ways to navigate the impact of automation trends, most likely by re-skilling as needed.

Comment: It's often hard to find good studies on the effect of minimum wage largely because so few people actually earn minimum wage, and for those that do it's usually temporary.  From basic economic principles though, a price floor necessarily results in lower consumption. So for every X people who have their wages raised there will be some number Y jobs made unprofitable and therefore never put out for hire. Unfortunately that Y number is largely invisible.How do you detect and quantify jobs that never come into existence in the first place? Bastiat's "Seen and Unseen" essay is good on that subject.

Comment: @Perkins agree.  It's more a "possible lever to look at" rather than a definitive answer.

Comment: A lower minimum wage ensures poor people spend less.  Therefore, a low minimum wage is bad for business *and* bad for employment.

Comment: @gerrit That's your claim, but I have yet to see much that is very numerically clear about that (or the opposite claim, which has a longer history of being peddled).  What I do see is that this is a subject that will attract endless controversy but is likely to have an impact one way or the other.

Comment: @gerrit  So the issue in that line of thinking is that the money to pay the higher rate doesn't appear by magic.  Paying one set of people more necessarily comes at the expense of paying some other set of people less.  Precisely who those groups are can be hard to determine, but in terms of spending in the economy it doesn't actually make any difference overall. Some workers get paid more, but then other jobs don't exist at all and the next thing you know you have to start up "spread the work" schemes to encourage employers to hire more people for fewer hours each to bring down unemployment.

Comment: @Perkins Depends; people on minimum wage getting an extra €100/month may be more likely to spend it (locally) than people who are well off, where that extra money may just end up pushing real estate prices further up as more people can afford more expensive housing.  But one can reason in many ways.  If only we could reliably apply the scientific method to the economy, such that economic predictions actually had value ;-)

Comment: @gerrit Even the money pushing up real-estate prices though then has to go somewhere...  Unless the wealthy people are literally playing Scrooge McDuck and keeping a massive vault of cash used solely for their personal, non-economic entertainment the money keeps moving. And there's a strong incentive for rich people to hire poor people rather than rich people because poor people are willing to do more work for any given quantity of money. If you want an economic framework that produces consistent, usable predictions, read Von Mises.

Comment: @Perkins If that money has to go somewhere, maybe the speculation money that pushes up real estate prices could go to provide homes for the people priced out of the market… and what's actually happening is that rather than rich people hiring poor people using money from real estate, they rent out real estate to poor people, leading to yet more money flow from the poor to the rich.  There's no such thing as money trickling down from the rich to the poor, in the real world money trickles up, not down (example: fastest ever growth in billionaires during coronavirus pandemic).

Comment: @gerrit Nonsense. A lower minimum wage means jobs that were previously legislated out of existence are now available, and the people who would have worked them had they been available now can, whereas previously they were excluded from working at all.

Comment: @Gerrit maybe, just maybe, my answer isn't the best place to engage into a long debate about the coupling, or not, in whichever direction,  of minimum wage to employment?  Though it might make for a question either here or SE.Economics.

Comment: @gerrit so it gets complicated because it flows both ways. E.g.:  Standard oil made millions (a benefit to the rich) by chopping the price of kerosene by over 75% (a benefit to the poor.) At the same time, there are non-economic factors at play. (Small stores ordered closed for lockdowns while billionaire-owned chains kept open.) Your example of housing has a ton of non-economic factors at play. Dig into the kinds of manipulations done via the zoning code to make sure only the wealthy can play in real-estate for starters. Bastiat has some good essays on how to sort out how the flow behaves.

Answer (score 1):

> Exactly how can government boost up employment numbers in a capitalistic society?

**Role of government in a capitalist society**
In a capitalist society government has no business boosting employment numbers or otherwise interfering in the economy. Its functions are limited to the basic tasks, such as maintaining the army, assuring the rule of law, assuring basic security (e.g., by maintaining the fire stations), etc. *It is not the role of a capitalist government to decide what is good and/or do good.* See, e.g., [Capitalism and Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalism_and_Freedom) by Friedman (Marxist refer to this system as *wild capitalism*):

> The role of government just considered is to do something that the market cannot do for itself, namely, to determine, arbitrate, and enforce the rules of the game.

**Post-depression: "social-capitalism"?**
However, as has been pointed in some other answers, since the Great Depression no western government is truly *capitalist*. Politically the essence of the Keynsian reforms (successfully implemented at the time everywhere in the west, from England and US to Nazi Germany and Fascist Italy), was that the government should assume an active role in managing economy and assuring the economic well-being of the population. Thus, no modern capitalist is truly capitalist - rather they differ by different degree of government interference in economic affairs.

To quote [the Investopedia article on Keynsian economics](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/keynesianeconomics.asp):

> The intervention of government in economic processes is an important part of the Keynesian arsenal for battling unemployment, underemployment, and low economic demand. The emphasis on direct government intervention in the economy often places Keynesian theorists at odds with those who argue for limited government involvement in the markets.

**Remark:** A good example of this misuse of term *capitalism* is the expression *crony capitalism*, which means influencing the government or abusing the government power for financial gain. Obviously, this requires a government that is allowed to interfere in economic affairs, which is not the case in a capitalist society.

Comment: Assuring the rule of law and assuring basic security inherently involve a government deciding what is good or bad.

Comment: @DavidHammen it is a rule-based government. It is deciding what is good or bad in the sence that it applies the rules to each situation. But it is not changing the definition or make up new functions/powers for itself.

Comment: Dueling used to be a legal and honorable way to settle a dispute in many countries. Now it's illegal almost everywhere. That's but one example. Governments regularly changed their views on whether something is good or bad.

Comment: @DavidHammen You do not understand what I am talking about or you think that my wording is imprecise? Let's not clutter coments with a long discussion.

Comment: I think you have given a highly opinionated answer based on what you think qualifies as capitalism. Governments do decide on what is good or not. Sometimes they mess up, badly (e.g., the eighteenth amendment of the U.S. Constitution), but deciding what is good or not is a key role of governments, regardless of classification as capitalist, Marxist, something in between, or something else.

Comment: @DavidHammen Feels to me like a cross-talk.

Answer (score -3):

In many western countries the blame is correclty placed on the govt for unemployment. But not because they have done too little. Rather because they have done too much.

In 2020 the average OECD country had a [ratio of taxes collected to GDP of 35%.](https://www.oecd.org/tax/tax-policy/revenue-statistics-highlights-brochure.pdf) The largest single player is the government. The second largest player in any given region is usually the state or provincial govt.

They set all the rules. In the US, the rules of the federal govt run to
[more than 50 thousand pages.](https://ballotpedia.org/Federal_Register_tops_70,000_pages_(2020)#:%7E:text=It%20is%20a%20common%20measure,pages%20and%2056%2C254%20pages%2C%20respectively.)
​Rules are set  for  every  imaginable ​thing regarding the ecomony. Wages, prices, inspections, hours of work and operation, who can work, what licenses they require, what insurance they must carry, what training they must have. And so on, for thousands of pages.

If there is something wrong with the economy the only place to look is the govt.

The Great Depression is often proferred up as the example of how govt can save us from the horrors of free market. This is a huge distortion.

The market of the 1920s was heavily influenced by the US Federal Reserve. They kept interest rates low and credit easy. This produced artificial bubbles which, no surprise, eventually burst. You may not be aware of the stock market crash of 1920. On a percent basis it was worse than 1929. But in 1920, the govt did not react quickly. And by the time they had, the market had righted itself and continued on with adjustments to the burst bubble. Some companies went broke. Others started with new arrangements.

[In 1929 they did react.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691003548)  The Fed started playing games with interest rates and moving gold around. The US govt reacted with the [Smoot-Hawley tarrif act,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoot%E2%80%93Hawley_Tariff_Act#:%7E:text=Hawley%2C%20it%20was%20signed%20by,only%20the%20Tariff%20of%201828.)
which set off an international trade war. Internally the [US govt began](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0060936428)
a series of interventions into everything from electric utilities to how butchers were allowed to sell chickens. And continual manipulation of interest rates, often totally arbitrarily.

The economy began to behave like a frightened child. New businesses that did start were often crushed by unpredictable changes in interest rates, financial laws, and labor regulations. Many people sat on whatever cash they could get, hoping things would settle down.

Thus the Great Depression bumbled along for 11 years until Pearl Harbor. The day after the attack, Roosevelt got all new economic advisors. And his one word command to them was: Production. He needed every type of war material. And they responded that the thing to do was unleash industry and commerce. Kill all the laws that the New Deal had placed on their backs. And let them produce. This was largely done. And the result was a boom.

At the start of WWII, the US had [seven aircraft carriers.](https://bluejacket.com/ww2_12-07-41_carriers.html#:%7E:text=On%207%20December%201941%2C%20the,was%20considered%20an%20auxiliary%20vessel.) By the end of the war [they had 105.](https://www.lacrosselibrary.org/sites/default/files/u117/05-aircraft_carriers_rule_the_pacific.pdf) Corresponding numbers of support craft were created, and port facilities to service and fuel them.

How did this happen? The industrialists were unchained. When a navy officer said he wanted ships he did not tell them how to make them. He did not say they had to pay any given price. He did not say who had to work in the factory or for how long or for what pay. He just said "SHIPS!" And the industrialist found ways to make things work better. Innovation after innovation which the industrialists were now free to use. From what hours to where the factory was located to pay premiums for night shift.

Today the biggest problem with govt interference is not the taxes. These are a huge problem, but not the biggest. Even the interest rate meddling is only a normal problem.

The existential problem is spending. Corporations become [milking-machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_milking)
to obtain government funding. They move away from things that would be productive. They cease to care about doing things that are good for their clients. They care only about what will get them more money from the govt.

In a free market, those companies that provide products that their customers believe are good, those companies thrive. In a mixed economy with too much govt spending, those companies thrive that play the suck-up-to-the-govt game. A bank that gets any of the various govt support from TARP to Fanny and Freddy, will out-compete a bank that tries to stay away from such. The govt suck-ups will survive and get investment. They will take the best employees. An aircraft company that plays the military-industrial-complex game will make $billions. And shitty airplanes. And the non-crony companies get squashed.

The thing govt should do is get smaller. Much smaller. In every aspect and avenue. Less taxes. Less regulation. Less programs. But most especially, less spending.

Comment: So the "unfettered industrialists" created the jobs by building aircraft carriers without government intervention did they? And who paid for the aircraft carriers? Governments. Using taxes. This answer is clearly living in a whole different universe from the real one.

Comment: Whether or not Austrian or Keynesianism economics is right, the answer to the question is simply that governments pursue policies, that are at least *intended* to promote economic growth, whether or not they work, which is why unemployment is viewed as the fault of the government.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yeah, I knew there's be a "weak man" fallacy in here before long.

Comment: @HHuang  So we take the statements of govt about their intent to be evidence of something?

Comment: @Dan I lean pretty anti-state in a general sense, but I still think that most government macroeconomic policy isn’t designed to *maliciously* damage the economy.

Comment: @HHuang Nancy Pelosi's net personal worth is over $130 million. Insider trading is not barred to congress reps. My own govt does the following. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WE_Charity_scandal Govt action is designed to enrich themselves and their friends.

Comment: @HHuang It's not.  It's apathetic about the economy as a whole.  Farmers don't hate their pigs, they just have incentives that conflict with those of their pigs, and all the power.

Comment: @HHuang The metaphor of pig farmer is exactly right. That is precisely how govt treats citizens. Livestock to be raised for slaughter. Oh, it's not malicious. They don't hate their pigs. They *LOVE* bacon.

Comment: This answer is off the wall, you seem to have studied the Great Depression & WW2 in a different universe to our own.

Comment: Reads more like a rant than anything else.  Aircraft carriers are an expense, not an investment in any economic sense.  The modern military industrial complex, culminating in the F35 and the NASA SLS system, have little to do with the constant tinkering and accelerated experimentation of WW2 years where failure meant losing the war rather than losing the pork.  But that activity, appropriate to wartime doesn't necessarily translate well to peacetime.  Mostly this reads like a tedious passage about "captains of industry" in Atlas Shrugged.  At least it's shorter.

Comment: 1920, right after 2 years of a fairly horrible war, with its associated buildup and reconstruction, does not necessarily map to 10 years later.  Just like rebuilding in 1950-1960 wasn't the solution to stagflation in the 80s.  Last, IIRC, the Great Depression was partially prolonged by initial government insistence that it didn't need to intervene much and that it mostly needed to balance its budget.  Something Japan started to do in the 90s - watching budget balances - before completely reversing course to stop deflation and getting that wrong as well.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica So the free market recovering on it's own in less than a year is unremarkable *because* it happened just 2 years after WWI? Whereas, 11 years of GD after the *roaring* 20s is SOO much harder to recover from. Yeah, you are responding with ideology not facts or rational argument.